# Audit Procedures used on SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've inherited a database recently which contains thousands of stored procedures and functions, however most of them are deprecated and no longer in use.

I've started adding a piece of code to the stored procedures one at time to notify me if they run, but this process is really quite manual.

Is there any way to start an audit, and see which stored procedures run in the next month or two without adding a piece of code to each stored procedure manually?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: How are these procs going to be run in the next month or two? This might be kind of a silly question: are these procs part of a sql server job? Are they going to be run manually?

Comment: Both, and that's the issue.
I can sortof see what's run in jobs, though I may get false positives from code that's been commented. But the DB can be accessed by jobs, other DBs, cognos, asp code, and other ways that I'm sure that I don't know.
So, before removing superfluous procs, I need to be sure that they don't run.

Comment: If you are really interested in looking for any procs that has been run recently, there is quite a number of ways to do that.

Comment: Can you suggest one that would work on sql server 2005?
I tried with sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats, but it only works of sql server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to be on SQL Server 2005 SP2 or higher. In prior versions of SQL Server, the OBJECT_NAME function only accepts a parameter for object_id.

Hopefully this should work for you:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(dest.[dbid]) AS 'databaseName'
    , OBJECT_NAME(dest.objectid) AS 'procName'
    , MAX(deqs.last_execution_time) AS 'last_execution'
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
WHERE dest.[TEXT] LIKE '%yourTableName%' -- replace
    And dest.[dbid] = DB_ID()  -- exclude ad-hocs
GROUP BY DB_NAME(dest.[dbid])
    , OBJECT_NAME(dest.objectid)
ORDER BY databaseName
    , procName
OPTION (MaxDop 1);
```